# How do I listen for messages sent from wear activity?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an Android Wear app that sends messages to the handheld device. The handheld device that is supposed to receive the messages does not have any app UIs and thus no MainActivity. How do I get it to receive messages from the wearable?

Is there a broadcast triggered when Google Play Services receives a message from a wearable that I can use to launch a service?

This is what I have so far in the mobile application:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    public ListenerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.v("Test", "ListenerService.onMessageReceived()");
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service
        android:name=".ListenerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

The wearable sends a message but the `onMessageReceived()` is not fired.

Comment: did you follow the official documentation? there you have a full implementation.

Comment: you have to implement the `WearableListenerService` on the `Handheld` too.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla The official documentation does assume the handheld device has a MainActivity. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html

Comment: you could also receive the message trough fragments and services... change your context. BTW, you are not following the correct documentation.

Comment: @Blackbelt I was thinking that was the right way to go. I tried implementing it but onMessageReceived() doesn't seem to be triggered in that service. I have the service defined in the AndroidManifest file too. `<service android:name=".ListenerService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" ></service>`

Comment: update your question. Post the Manifest and subclass of the WearableListenerService you are using on the Handheld

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla There are no fragments on the handheld, and services need to be explicitly started. I need the app to respond even though no services are started and no activities are running.

Comment: @mushroom you cloud also download the android wear project (it comes with android studio) and use that wearable service. EDIT: It a service that listen any message you send to the device.

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question :)

Comment: you are missing the intent filter for the service in the manifest. Add      `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: @Blackbelt Thank you, if you would write that as an answer I would select it. I did read the docs but I must have missed that out, so you were really of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

`BIND_LISTENER` is deprecated now. It has to be replaced with

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
 </intent-filter>
```

more info [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/bind-listener).

***old answer***

You missed the `intent-filter` in your Manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/> 
</intent-filter>
```